# HTML to PDF conversion in php online

Tags: php, wkhtmltopdf

I've been trying to develop a php program that can convert an html file to pdf. I Googled the issue and found out this software [wkHTMLtoPDF](http://wkhtmltopdf.org/) software which can be used for this purpose.
 I downloaded it for the windows and i successfully created what i wanted to using these lines:

```
  $wkcommand = "\"C:\\Program Files\\wkhtmltopdf\\bin\\wkhtmltopdf\" --page-width 300 --page-height      225 \"$url\" $dir\\$tempName.pdf &";
        exec($wkcommand, $output, $error);
```

As these lines run in command line and works perfectly, now i want to make my website online but i can't understand how i will use this service online because i'm going to use a free web hosting service like: [www.base.pk](http://www.base.pk) for this purpose. How can i use this tool for conversion there?

Comment: I didn't understand your question... You just have to put these lines in some PHP script that is running in your server.

Comment: dear these lines are using a tool to perform the task. That tool is WKHTMLTOPDF, where to put that tool then?

Comment: In my server, I just installed the right version to my operating system (http://wkhtmltopdf.org/downloads.html), and then, it was in the path and the exec command worked well.

Comment: Brother how you installed it there. I'm just a windows user.

Comment: If your problem is "how to install wkhtmltopdf in your server", maybe it's better ask here: http://serverfault.com/

Comment: can i install this service on a free hosting like i mentioned in the question?

Comment: @SubhanAhmed depends on the free hosting environment. There is no answer to cover all of the hosts out there, some maybe might allow you to install, but I Highly doubt that you will find a free one that will allow you to do that. At least I've never heard of one.

Comment: It's not even necessary to install it. It's just a binary. If the host allows executing binaries on the server (yes, this is not a given, especially on free hosting), you're in to the party.

Answer (score 0):

Usually shared hosting providers forbid to run ssh commands. 
It means that you can't run exec().
And also it means that you need the SERVER (virtual or dedicated) so you would be able to configure that there.