# Installing phpwkhtmltopdf by mikehaertl

Tags: php, wkhtmltopdf

I've spent hours on this problem and still got nothing. I'm quite a noob when it comes to installing something rather than double clicking may that's why i'm stuck.

What i want to do is to develop a web service which takes a url and returns an image file of the screen shot of that url.
I found out that i can do this doing the following steps:

1. Using wkhtmltopdf to convert my html files to pdf
2. And then converting this pdf to image using php imagic library.

I'm still on the first step. I downloaded an executable for wkhtmltopdf from some website and by using the following lines in command line, i successfully created a pdf:

```
\"C:\\Program Files\\wkhtmltopdf\\bin\\wkhtmltopdf\" --page-width 300 --page-height 225 \"$url\"    $dir\\$tempName.pdf &
```

But now i wanted to make this as a web service online but this lines just run on cmd, not on a shared hosting server. What to do know? I've also seen phpwkhtmltopdf but i don't understand the installation phase as disscused [Here.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22372775/installation-of-mikehaertl-phpwkhtmltopdf-on-xampp-for-dummies)

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I get WKHTMLTOPDF to execute via PHP?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5663814/how-do-i-get-wkhtmltopdf-to-execute-via-php)

Comment: possible duplicate of [HTML to PDF conversion in php online](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27459607/html-to-pdf-conversion-in-php-online)